# Método estático não tem acesso a variavel da classe

Tags: c#, variáveis, unity-5, métodos-estáticos

Olá, estou com o seguinte problema:
   Tenho um método estático que usa uma variável de sua classe, porém o Unity me da o seguinte erro:

> \Assets\Scripts\GameControl.cs(3,3):
>   Error CS0120: Uma referência de objeto
>   é necessária para o campo, método ou a
>   propriedade não estática
>   'GameControl.healthText' (CS0120)
>   (Assembly-CSharp)

Aqui está o código do script "GameControl.cs"(apenas código relevante):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameControl : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text healthText;
    public static int healthBar = 100;

    public static void UpdateHealthBar(){
        healthText.text = "Health \n" + healthBar;
    }
}
```

[image: Atribuição a vaiavél]

Aqui o código do outro arquivo que está chamando o método(apenas relevante):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyScript : MonoBehaviour {
void Update(){
        gameObject.transform.Translate (dir.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime,Space.World);

        if (Vector3.Distance (transform.position, target[wayPoint].position) <= 0.4f) {
            if (wayPoint < target.Length - 1) {
                wayPoint++;
                dir = target [wayPoint].position - gameObject.transform.position;
            } else {
                Destroy (this.gameObject);
                GameControl.healthBar--;
                GameControl.UpdateHealthBar();       //Aqui<<<
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Bom, percebi que se instanciar a classe no arquivo de deixar a classe apenas pública não obtenho o erro, porém quero evitar essa solução. Por que esse erro ocorre, e, como posso resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ocorre porque membros estáticos não fazem parte do escopo do objeto e sim da classe.

Supondo que exista a classe `Game` com os seguintes membros

- `string Nome`
- `string Produtor`
- `static string Versao`

Então, `Versao` será acessível **sem instanciar a classe**

`Game.Versao`

Já os outros dois membros serão acessíveis apenas na instância da classe

```
Game game = new Game();
game.Nome;
game.Produtor;
```

Uma possível solução pro seu caso é fazer com que `healthText` seja também um membro estático. Parece que isso que você precisa, já que todos os outros membros também são estáticos.